# How can I use Rules to send an e-mail to the author of a node linked by an entity reference field?

Tags: rules, entities, tokens

I have a content type called **Help Wanted**.  I have another content type called **Reply to Help Wanted**.  The reply content type includes an entity reference field that contains a node reference to the original help wanted ad being replied to.

I am trying to use Rules to send an e-mail when a reply is posted to the author of the original **Help Wanted** post.

However, I don't know what to put in the **To** field of the *Send mail* action.  I tried the following:

```
[node:field_my_entityreference:author:mail]
```

But this token didn't work.  I also tried several other variations to no effect.  Is it possible to use tokens to get the author's e-mail of a node linked by entity reference?  If not, how do I get the author's e-mail via the entity reference?

Comment: Hey Patrick, the above worked for me perfectly just now in a quick test.  However, I used the 'direct input mode' rather than the tokens to select all the fields.  Have you tried that?

Comment: PHP filter module could be an option

Comment: I'm so glad it worked!  I did add it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I got mine to work:

1. Switch to '**Data selection mode**' which is not how the mail action launches by default:
   [image]
2. Select through the field sequence just like you already had with tokens!
   [image]

I noticed that the tokens are otherwise not available if you just use the direct input mode.  Weird!